# Utilizing a Map properly

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, but learning quite well and been reading and understanding newer and better ways of Java.

Currently my issue right now is with using Map storing.
As seen below this is how I'm storing the information in my class.

```
public Map<String , Object> req = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public void putReq() {  
   req.put("npcKills", 0); 
}
```

I'm looking for help on adding the stored variable to a saving script I'm using.
Here's a regular usage of another save I'm currently using.

```
characterfile.write("logsCut = ", 0, 10);
characterfile.write(Integer.toString(Player.logsCut), 0, Integer.toString(Player.logsCut).length());
characterfile.newLine();
```

As you can see I want to implement my "npcKills" variable to the save script, just not entirely sure on how it's supposed to go. *uses BufferedWritter btw*

I'm also looking to find a addition to the value on demand so normally my int incrementing would be `p.npcKills += 1;`

I want to do that, but using the map.

Comment: yourMap.get("npcKills"); gets the stored value

Comment: Please note that maps are used for storing keys and values. For instance storing a customer ID with a customer object. The usage you have above is a little smelly IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
map.get("npcKills");
```

To get the values of the stored variables

To increment each value, you would have to do

```
map.put("npcKills", map.get("npcKills") + 1);
```

There is no easy way to increment the values

Comment: I got the incrementing to work now, the problem is the saving though.
      server.model.content.compcape.CompCape.putReq();
      int npcKillcount = (Integer) server.model.content.compcape.CompCape.req.get("npcKills");
      server.model.content.compcape.CompCape.req.put("npcKills", (npcKillcount + 1));
      System.out.println(server.model.content.compcape.CompCape.req.get("npcKills").toString());

This is the saving
   characterfile.write("npcKillCount = ", 0, 15);
   characterfile.write(p.getCompCape().req.get("npcKills").toString());
   characterfile.newLine();